# How to list out all the descriptions in selection box from two array list

Tags: java, arrays, jsp

Sorry im new to JSP , I'm trying to list out all the descriptions in selection box by combining two array list description but i failed. Appreciate for help.

```
-------------------JSP -----------------------------
     ArrayList alRiskFactor = new ArrayList();
     ArrayList exRiskFactor = new ArrayList();
    SQL = "SELECT A.CODE,A.DESCP FROM TB_RISKFACTOR A, TB_TR_MAINRULE B WHERE A.CODE=B.RFACTOR AND B.UKEY='"+TARIFFTYPE+"' AND A.TYPE='TR' WITH UR";
    DB_Tariff.executeQuery(SQL);    
    while(DB_Tariff.getNextQuery()){
        ArrayList alInner   = new ArrayList();
        String code     = common.setNullToString(DB_Tariff.getColumnString("CODE"));
        String descp    = common.setNullToString(DB_Tariff.getColumnString("DESCP"));

        alInner.add(code);
        alInner.add(descp);         
        alRiskFactor.add(alInner);
    }
    SQL = "SELECT A.CODE,A.DESCP FROM TB_RISK_FACTOR_SETUP A, TB_TR_MAINRULE B WHERE A.CODE=B.RFACTOR AND B.UKEY='"+TARIFFTYPE+"' WITH UR";
    DB_Tariff.executeQuery(SQL);    
    while(DB_Tariff.getNextQuery()){
        ArrayList alInner   = new ArrayList();
        String code     = common.setNullToString(DB_Tariff.getColumnString("CODE"));
        String descp    = common.setNullToString(DB_Tariff.getColumnString("DESCP"));

        alInner.add(code);
        alInner.add(descp);         
        exRiskFactor.add(alInner);
    }
```

Below part is what I'm currently did, I'm trying to combine both array list to list out all the descriptions. Yet it's only show the second Array description.

```
------------------------------HTML--------------------------

 <select name="RISKFACTOR" style="width: 300px;" onchange="fnReload('F');">
         <option value="" selected>Select Tariff Type</option>
         <%for(Iterator i = alRiskFactor.iterator(); i.hasNext();){
          ArrayList alInner = (ArrayList) i.next();
          String code       = (String) alInner.get(0);
          String descp      = (String) alInner.get(1);

         %>
          <%for(Iterator e = exRiskFactor.iterator(); i.hasNext();){
           alInner  = (ArrayList) e.next();
           code     = (String) alInner.get(0);
           descp        = (String) alInner.get(1);

         %>
          <option value="<%=code%>" <%= code.equals(RISKFACTOR)?"selected":"" %>><%=descp%></option>
         <%}}%>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem seems to be that you are only creating the `option` elements inside the loop for the second list.  Try this code:

```
------------------------------HTML--------------------------

<select name="RISKFACTOR" style="width: 300px;" onchange="fnReload('F');">
    <option value="" selected>Select Tariff Type</option>
    <%for(Iterator i = alRiskFactor.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
        ArrayList alInner = (ArrayList) i.next();
        String code       = (String) alInner.get(0);
        String descp      = (String) alInner.get(1);

    %>
    <option value="<%=code%>" <%= code.equals(RISKFACTOR)?"selected":"" %>><%=descp%></option>
    <%}%>
    <%for(Iterator e = exRiskFactor.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
        alInner  = (ArrayList) e.next();
        code     = (String) alInner.get(0);
        descp        = (String) alInner.get(1);

    %>
    <option value="<%=code%>" <%= code.equals(RISKFACTOR)?"selected":"" %>><%=descp%></option>
    <%}%>
</select>
```

Comment: Awesome !! Thousand of thanks to you @JasonMAcher ...!!

What a silly mistake I've done, only open 1 option tag for two arraylist..

Comment: It is an easy thing to overlook when you deal with code generating other code.  :)